# wordpress/woocommerce login url not redirecting correctly

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, login, password

I'm trying to resolve the following issue.

When a user adds his email on the lost-password page an email is sent to them.

The url however is
https://cormilu.com.br/minha-conta/lost-password/?key=...... instead of 
cormilu.com.br/wp-login?...

Due to this when clicking the link the user is redirected back to the lost-password page and is unable to reset his password.

To duplicate the error please enter 
https://cormilu.com.br/minha-conta/lost-password/

I've already saved the permalinks, disabled the theme, plugins, and deactivated the htaccess file.

Does anybody have an idea what might be causing this?

Thanks and looking forward to hearing from you.

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

Solved the issue.

I use varnish on my site and this was causing the problem.
If you use varnish too exclude the my-account page and the following cookie from your varnish:
wp-resetpass-.?